# Prestashop 1.6.1.19 - remove delivery calculation step 1 checkout

Tags: php, html, prestashop, cart

PrestaShop version 1.6.1.19

As of now, PrestaShop's first step of the checkout process for the customer is showing a calculated delivery.

This delivery calculation doesn't seem logical for us to in step 1, as step 4 is already giving the customer an opportunity to choose whether to pickup in-store or have delivery.

Therefore, we wish to only get the price of this product in the first step of the checkout.

I know it's required to make some changes to the PHP files or similar - but I don't know where to look for these steps in those files.

Comment: Frankly, it sounds like what you need is a freelancer developer

Comment: I can do most of the code by my self - I just need to know where to find these files :-) since I've been working with Wordpress for a long time I have no clue about prestashop.
So I just need someone with a bit of experience with prestashop who can tell me where these steps of check out / buy process is. :-)

Comment: I am not profficient in prestashop, but I would start with http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Developer+Guide